# Joining the table creating a duplicate entry in laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I just want to merge the content of 2 tables and display it based on the ID.

Both the table has 3 entries.

Table a - Sampling order

```
Date Docname Products Quantity ID
1     A       A         1      1
2     B       B         2      1 
3     C       C         3      1
```

Table B - Representative locations

```
Date Area lat long ID
 1    a    1   1   1
 2    b    2   2   1
 3    c    3   3   1
```

The output should generate like 3 rows with all the table A columns and B columns where ID = Specified ID

I need a output like this

```
Date Docname product Quantity Area lat long
1      A       A       1       a    1   1
2      B       B       2       b    2   2
3      C       C       3       c    3   3
```

But its generating 9 rows (3*3) and duplicating the numbers of rows present in both the tables.
Its generating

```
Date Docname product Quantity Area lat long
1      A       A       1       a    1   1
2      B       B       2       b    2   2
3      C       C       3       c    3   3
1      A       A       1       a    1   1
2      B       B       2       b    2   2
3      C       C       3       c    3   3
1      A       A       1       a    1   1
2      B       B       2       b    2   2
3      C       C       3       c    3   3
```

Combing number of rows in A * B - I just need only 3 rows with respect to ID.

Query -

```
$Report = DB::table('sampling_order')
             ->join('representativelocations','representativelocations.representativeid','=','sampling_order.representativeid')
             ->select('sampling_order.representativeid as representativeid',
             'sampling_order.date as date',
             'sampling_order.doctor_name as doctor_name',
             'sampling_order.products as products',
             'sampling_order.quantity as quantity',
             'representativelocations.latitude as latitude',
             'representativelocations.longitude as longitude',
             'representativelocations.area as area')
             ->whereBetween('sampling_order.date', [$Datefrom, $Dateto])
             ->where('sampling_order.representativeid','=',$Representativeid)->get();
```

Comment: Seems like there is an issue with the join (representativelocations) table. 
Table sampling_order contains 3 records as of now. And second table contains 3 records. I just want to merge both based on the id.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on the requirement, i think you should try joining on `date` not `ID` as below. This will return `3` rows as you are expecting.

```
select so.date,so.Docname,so.products,so.Quantity,rl.Area,rl.lat,rl.long from Sampling_order AS so
INNER JOIN  Representative_locations as rl ON so.Date = rl.Date
WHERE so.ID = 1
```

Change table names and column names as needed.

Comment: Did you use distinct ?

Comment: distinct is returning 6 rows now

Comment: Can you post the exact expected output and the table structure with datatypes and PK's?

Comment: Edited the required output and generating output.

Answer (score 0):

What I can see, all Id is '1' in two tables,
so it should be 3 * 3 = 9 rows in result.
I guess you may want this:

id product area-A area-B area-C

1____A____1____2_____3

1____B____2____3_____4

if so. you need to join three times.

```
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *, area AS area-A FROM B WHERE area = 'a' ) AS B ON B.id = A.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *, area AS area-B FROM B WHERE area = 'b' ) AS C ON C.id = A.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *, area AS area-C FROM B WHERE area = 'c' ) AS D ON D.id = A.id
```

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: If 4 entries present in 2 tables, it is returning 16 rows. 3 is just an example.

Comment: I want Date Docname product quantity lat long area from those 2 tables. I just want to merge the data with respect to ID